# What are my next steps if Metadata Rejected?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I've added a description `Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life.` to all App Localizations.

Then click “Save".

Then I send message in Resolution Center.

Should I click "Submit for Review"?

> From Apple
>   2.16 - Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion,
>   local notifications, etc.
>   2.16 Details
>
> Your app uses the Location Background mode but does not include the
>   required "battery use" disclaimer in your Application Description.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please add the following disclaimer to your Application Description:
>
> "Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically
>   decrease battery life."
>
> Since your iTunes Connect Application State is Metadata Rejected, we
>   do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit iTunes
>   Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values.
>   Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution
>   Center and we will continue the review.
>
> NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all App
>   Localizations by selecting each specific localization and making
>   appropriate changes.

Comment: Wow man, they say clearly "we don't require a new version" and "reply to this message and we will continue the review". So... No submission for review required.

Answer (score 0):

As apple review team clearly mentioned they don't need new binary upload since its metadata rejection. So once you added this text suggested by the apple team than its done.

Go for it & submit it for review. It will be approved by apple team.

I hope it will help you.